# Post - Cannot GET error - Local server

Tags: javascript, api, express, post, routes

I am trying to create an API using a local server for testing. The route
'GET' works fine, however 'POST' has a problem and it is returning 'Cannot GET /add/name'. I am developing the API using node.js and Express. Why am I receiving get when the route is set to 'POST'? Where is the problem?

```
var fs = require('fs');
var data = fs.readFileSync('events.json');
var allEvents = JSON.parse(data);

console.log(allEvents);
console.log('Server running.');

var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var sever = app.listen(3000, listening);

function listening() {
    console.log('Serving...');
}

app.use(express.static('website'));

//GET and send all data from JSON
app.get('/all', sendAll);

function sendAll(request, response) {
    response.send(allEvents);
}

//POST new data to JSON
app.post('/add/:name', addData);

function addData(request, response) {

  var newData = request.params;
  var name = newData.name;
  var eventType = newData.eventType;
  var reply;

  // var newEvent = {
  //   name: ":name",
  //   eventType: ":eventType",
  // };

  var newData = JSON.stringify(allEvents, null, 2);
  fs.writeFile('events.json', newData, finished);

  function finished(err) {
      console.log('Writting');
      console.log(err);
      var reply = {
          word: word,
          score: score,
          status: 'Success'
      }
      response.send(reply);
  }
}
```

Request

```
$(function() {
  //HTML
    var $list = $('#list');

    var jsonURL = '../events.json'

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/all',
        success: function(data) {
      console.log('Data received', data);
            $.each(data, function (type, string) {
                $list.append('<li>' + type + " : " + string + '</li>');
            });
        },
        error: function (err) {
            console.log('Error, data not sent.', err);
        }
    });

    $('#submit').on('click', function () {

        // var newEvent = {
        //  name: $name.val(),
    //   eventType: $eventType.val(),
        // };

    var name = $('#fieldName').val();
    var eventType = $('#fieldEventType').val();
    console.log(name);

        $.ajax({
            type: 'PUT',
            url: '/add/' + name,
            success: function (addData) {
                $list.append('<li>name: ' + name + '</li>');
            },
            error: function (err) {
                console.log('Error saving order', err);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: How are you calling it from the client? I hope you didn't just paste `http://localhost:3000/add/some_item` in the address bar of your web browser expecting it to work?

Comment: Do you mean how I am running the server? Sorry, I am new to this.

Comment: No, I mean how are you calling the POST endpoint from the client? You make a request to your server, right? How are you making this request?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. Like I said my knowledge of coding is very limited. So replying your first question, yes, I did think I could add an object using the route. In this previous tutorial i followed [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42216635/jquery-ajax-post-404-error-local-server) I've managed to do it, but now trying on my own, something is not right.

Comment: @DiegoOriani — There are two parts to this. An HTTP server (and you've shown us the code for that) and an HTTP client (which could be a web browser, but you haven't shown us that). The error message you get says the client is sending a GET request. You haven't told us what you are doing to make the client make the request.

Comment: @Quentin thank you for the patience. Added the client side now.

Comment: None of that code looks like it should event attempt to make a POST request (and I wouldn't be surprised if it wasn't running properly because you were submitting a form at the same time).

Comment: @Quentin I though the server side would do the job of adding the 'value' captured from the client side to the JSON. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42216635/jquery-ajax-post-404-error-local-server) I managed to do it, but now trying it again something on the server side does not work.

Comment: You are making a GET request. The server is telling you that you are making a GET request. You haven't told the server to do anything when you make a GET request to that URL. You need to figure out why you are making a GET request and to stop doing that.

Answer (score 0):

For testing POST request, you can use Postman to test it. If you use the browser to call the api, it will be GET method instead of POST.

[image: POST request in postman]